# TypeError: Cannot read property 'freeze' of undefined

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I am trying to create a facade for the npm library [avsc](https://github.com/mtth/avsc). When I compile with `sbt fastOptJS::webpack` and open the .html file, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'freeze' of undefined` from the file `treepad-fastopt-bundle.js` in the line `$g["Object"]["freeze"]($env);`. I don't use Object.freeze it anywhere.

This is the facade code:

```
import buffer.Buffer
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.{JSImport, JSName}

@js.native
trait Type extends js.Object {
  @JSName("val")
  def toBuffer(v: String): Buffer = js.native
}

@JSImport("avsc/", "avro")
@js.native
object avro extends avro

@js.native
trait avro extends js.Object {
  def parse(schema: js.Any): Type = js.native
}
```

Also have a look at the whole [project](https://github.com/Tamriel/treepad/blob/master/src/main/scala/avsc/avsc.scala), it's very little code.

Using `@JSImport("avsc", JSImport.Namespace)` instead did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that, in your [webpack configuration file](https://github.com/Tamriel/treepad/blob/ef09384cf8cbd36e4d26b48ade65e25e87dc461a/webpack.config.js#L3), you tell webpack to target the Node.js execution environment instead of web browsers.

However, as you noticed, the `avsc` module uses the `fs` Node.js module, which is not available in web browsers. It seems that the right workaround, in this case, is to add the following line to your webpack configuration file:

```
module.exports.node = { fs: "empty" };
```

Last but not least, the right `@JSImport` is indeed `@JSImport("avsc", JSImport.Namespace)` because you want to import the whole `avsc` module, as shown in [the documentation](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/blob/b42ac5b228c7d704fb1ed2453972783120cbbda0/README.md#examples).